# How to deal with constant changing questions

Tags: discussion, questions

I've been helping someone out with some JS/CSS in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23180952/keep-sub-menu-active-after-mouseout/) for the last five days. It seems every time I answer one problem, the question shifts onto something else. I have asked for the complete code in the comments, to avoid a 'moving goalpost' situation.

What's the best plan for something like this? I don't feel like it warrants a closure of the question, but it's getting to the point where a lot of what the OP is asking, can be found out by searching SO and Google.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vampire

Comment: Vampire problem, never heard of that before. Like it!

Comment: I usually refuse further help and ask them to post a new question.

Comment: Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188625/etiquette-for-russian-doll-questions

Comment: see: [Exit strategies for “chameleon questions”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)

Comment: My suggestion would be that it should be possible to flag an edit to a question as a "chameleon edit" so that somebody with the required privilege can roll it back.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

**Sigh** (not at you, but at the OP who keeps changing his or her question.)

I fell into these quicksands a few times before. I have a few strategies:

1. If the new problem is really a *different* question then point out to the OP that they are asking a different question and suggest that they post it as a different question. Sometimes this works.
2. Don't respond *quickly* to the OPs comment. Sometimes after a bit of time this works too. The OP sees the light on their own.
3. Delete my answer and move on. This is in cases where the original question was of borderline quality or the OP's comments indicate a lack of rigorous thinking, or that the question which was originally about X is turning in to a question about A, B, C, D and X. This is for cases where I estimate that the interaction is just going to be a huge drain on my time and probably extremely frustrating. The fact is that there is most likely someone else I could be helping who has asked a better question or is just more pleasant to help so...

   Why *delete* the answer? I don't trust the OP to not start editing the question into something that is different from what I answered, so...

   In this case, voting to close may be warranted. It really depends on how the question is framed. For instance if the OP modifies the question to ask what should be asked in two different questions, then "too broad" seems warranted. Or a question may become unclear due to an edit. Etc.

Comment: The edit question point was the main reason for me posting this. It was getting to the point where my original answer didn't resemble to original question in any way.

Comment: +1 for "delete my answer and move on" — it's the only thing that works in my own experience. (Particularly so when OP downvotes an otherwise correct answer that he doesn't want to hear.)

Comment: You should never delete your answer for such a reason. Rollback OPs question to the most suitable revision and explain they shouldn't change it drastically. If they won't listen and keep editing the question, flag it for moderator attention - the mods can then choose the correct path of action to take, such as locking the question in extreme cases.

Comment: @PeteSimmons FWIW, I use 1., possibly combined roll-back, then down-votes and vote to close if there is no reaction after a while (or if the reaction indicates no willingness to change.) Sometimes I add a note to my answer indicating what question I am actually answering. Most of the time, simply adding a comment pointing out the problem out suffices. I only delete my answer as a last resort.