# What is the best thing to do if one question leads to another?

Tags: discussion

What is the best way to handle a problem where a user asks a question, I answer it correctly, then they figure out they don't know how to implement it correctly? I've had this scenario a few times, and I'm always through into troubleshooting through chat or comments, and it's kind of annoying, because I know  I answered their question correctly, but the person becomes frustrated if I can't figure out where their next bug is.

Should I just tell them I answered their question right and to post a new question, or try to help them, or what?

Comment: Sounds like a case of the [xy-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I would always advise to ask a new question. If that's not significantly different it can be closed as duplicate. No need to spoon-feed people that are uninterested in learning.

Comment: Okay, take this one for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23395570/following-the-element-after-sorting-listivew I answered the question to the extent he asked, and now I'm sorting through the code he posted in his comments trying to find a solution. Should I ask him to post another question?

Comment: I have to say that the other "extreme" is equally frustrating. By which I mean: "I'm making tea, how do I turn the kettle on?" <answer>, accept. later: "where do I find a cup?" <answer>, accept. later: "how do I get a teabag into the cup?" <answer>, accept. later: "I am missing a spoon, where can I get one?" etc. All those questions may be predictable from the beginning, but the specific question asked and answer may be simple, and providing all the answers in one go may be off topic as too broad.

Comment: I do agree, @AD7six, that would be frustrating. Where would I draw the line though? I think that's just up to the users discretion/what codeMagic said.

Comment: For this question, I go with [option 1](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252129/761202); though sometimes that creates a new problem where readers need to have seen question 1 to understand question 2 - which leads to more frustration. In both extremes I find Option 2 particularly useful (Though the effectiveness depends on whether it's a topic where you yourself are a SME and nobody else offers an answer). Option 2 also helps both sides when it's evident that a user is simply not thinking about their problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If they are having trouble implementing the part that you solved then it sounds like it is related and it is ok to try and help them more, assuming you want to. If you are getting frustrated because you don't think they are trying, won't ever get it, or you just don't want to continue then you have the right to stop answering them.

If the issue is unrelated or will take up too much time/space on the existing post then suggesting them to create a new post with all of the relevant code that they now have would be ideal. It would be good to explain to them *why* you suggested them to create a new post. When I do this I usually say something like, "Please create a new post with the relevant code so we don't clog up this post and make it useless and too convoluted for others".

Some people are lazy and don't want to try to implement the answer on their own so they will leech on as long as they can until you get their program running. However, some aren't lazy at all but just don't understand that they should create a new post and why so it is good to inform them.

Comment: That'd probably be the best to do. I feel like a lot of times, the people who ask another question in their question tend not to edit their original question, and just post their code in comments or pastebin.

Comment: @ElectronicGeek That does happen. In the case of your link in the comment above, since the post isn't huge and messy already, sometimes I will ask them to edit their post with the new (most relevant) code while making sure not to change the OP. But this is entirely up to you. If you feel like you've done enough and don't want to continue then you can suggest a new post or simply stop responding.

Comment: For example, this case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23395570/following-the-element-after-sorting-listivew I feel as if I answered the question in full capacity and want to move on. I'm willing to help, but the info and code are all scattered.

Comment: That is the question I was referring to in my last comment. Since the OP is short and concise, asking the OP to add the code in the post could be beneficial to others and allow you to help them better. If the post was bigger then I would suggest a new question if they couldn't get it after giving it a try.

Comment: But wouldn't it be better to move to a new question because his first question is already answered, or not?

Comment: It wouldn't be a bad thing necessarily but I don't know about "better". The new question is directly related. You answered what needs to be used but the OP is stuck on how to implement it so it really isn't a separate question but it could be. As I said, since the post isn't too big and messy, I would suggest them to edit the code into the post. This will make it easier for you to help them further and for others with the same problem to have all of the information in one place. Again, it is up to you and either way would be fine.

Comment: You *did* give them an answer and it isn't your responsibility to get it working.

Comment: That's what I'm getting at. I feel that I've fulfilled what the user was asking, and that should be sufficient.