# Reject edit when OP tries to put their results into your answer?

Tags: discussion, edits

I put up an answer for this question:

[LINQ Union between two tables with the same fields and then returned in a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24420478/linq-union-between-two-tables-with-the-same-fields-and-then-returned-in-a-collec)

My answer all works fine for me but the OP had problems when they tried to run it.  The OP added a suggested edit on to my answer whereby they tried to append the results they had and some updated code.  I rejected the edit because it didn't seem to be the right place to put that information.

**Question:  Should I have rejected this edit?  Would the OP have been be better trying to convey their results as a comment or edited into the question?**

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I had a look at the [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5152670) and you were right to reject it, this is standard "Incorrect attempt to reply to the post".

The OP should have put the code in the question to begin with, but it sounds like this is code they hadn't written at the time, with a new problem which may warrant a new question. The answers you and Grant provided both appear to answer the original question and this just seems to be [moving the goalposts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252113/how-to-deal-with-constant-changing-questions).

Comment: Thanks for that.  I got the same impression as you.  The error he raised really had nothing to do with the answers that we gave.  The code in my answer is absolute bog-standard stuff.