# Questions that change/evolve over time. Is that fair?

Tags: discussion, questions

Is it fair to ask a question and once answers have been provided to change it?

In some cases, questions are being evolved over time more alike a dialog. This makes proposed answers invalid or inappropriate after the change.

Answering a question requires some effort and it is unfair to see that answers are rendered invalid because the question is adapted based on the information that is received.

Could you provide some guidance with respect to this situation?

Comment: No, such behavior is frowned upon, and edits to the question should be rolled back.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deal with constant changing questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252113/how-to-deal-with-constant-changing-questions), http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260066/drastic-question-revision

Comment: No comma missing, this is totally inappropriate. We do not allow questions to be changed so drastically that it invalidates existing answers. The edits should be rolled back and a comment to that effect should be left for the person who asked the question. If they persist, flag the question for moderator attention. Use a custom flag, explain the problem and ask them to lock the question.

Comment: Doesn't always work.  I flagged this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35861210/sum-to-infinity-is-the-algorithm-acceptable after the poster had twice edited the question so as to make existing answers irrelevant/wrong, and I had rolled it back.  Sure enough, after I flagged it, the OP vandalized the question a third time:(