# How to handle a questioner who won't try an answer?

Tags: discussion

I've gotten a LOT from this site, and I'm trying to start answering questions lately. I recently provided an answer to someone with a fair question about image resizing. However, instead of trying my (simple, working) solution, they kept asking for alternate solutions.

After two or three go-rounds in the comments, I just stopped replying. Should I have been more forceful in saying "Please just try what I told you to try?" Should I have just not followed up in comments at all?

In short, how do you help someone who won't even TRY your help?

Edit for clarity re [potential duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252113/how-to-deal-with-constant-changing-questions): The issue isn't that the question is being edited. The question is the same, the person just wants a different solution.

2nd Edit: Thanks to all! Answers/comments here made me feel more comfortable with and excited about contributing to this community.

Comment: I have some advice for you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=moSFlvxnbgk

Comment: I will take that to heart, thanks @cat

Comment: Okay, but seriously? Don't let it get to you too much, and don't worry too much about OP's willingness to try your help. If you crafted a good answer, then it may not be helpful to a stubborn OP but it will *undoubtedly* be helpful to people with the same questions in the future.

Comment: As someone who writes regex answers (and revises them, especially when the question is clarified), I've found that the OP sometimes is so dense they didn't notice I made a change. It may be necessary to reiterate that you have indeed done more. This may not be your situation, though.

Comment: Accepting or rejecting an answer is all upon OP's discretion. You should not take it to heart. The overall purpose of answering on SO should be to help a lot of people and not just one. If your answer is really good, other people with same problem in future would up-vote it.

Comment: I often find the OP's real "question" is, "Write this code for me." When my answer is, "If you do <this> it will solve your problem", they refuse, because they want me to "Write this code for me". In this case, I won't try more than once.

Comment: I've run into this a couple of times.  I use the time-tested parenting technique: "I'll be happy to help you move forward once you've tried this."

Of course, you have no obligation to help anyone.  As a good SO citizens, we help where we can -- I fully sympathize with your wanting to solve OP's problem.  However, in this case, there is an obvious mismatch: your help isn't what OP *wants*.  You either probe more to find out what OP actually wants, or gently decline to do more work until OP picks up his/her share of the work.

Comment: I've run into this twice.  One OP quickly realized that he wasn't working up to snuff, and figured out the rest of the problem overnight.  The other kept begging me to "write just this one more loop for me" after we'd gone through two postings and a private chat.  I chose to quit responding; the lack of OPs effort was painfully obvious.

Comment: Voting to reopen as none of the questions actually apply. This here is not about a question being constantly edited nor about an op wanting more than the answer.

Comment: I'd tell the OP that, in the future, any requirements that limit what kinds of answers will help them should be included in the question itself. They shouldn't invalidate existing answers by adding new requirements after the fact, but they should keep this in mind next time.

Comment: Can anyone tell what does "OP" stands for exactly ?

Comment: OP = Original Poster -- on StackOverflow,  the individual/user who posted the question.

Comment: @newguy you might find the [Stack Exchange Glossary - Dictionary of Commonly-Used Terms](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms) handy

Answer (score 68, accepted):

> In short, how do you help someone who won't even TRY your help?

You don't have to. They are not obligated to accept your help, and you don't have to continue if they really are seeking an alternative. Perhaps your suggestion simply doesn't adequately solve their problem. That's fine. Everyone has different requirements. I wouldn't blame the questioner for it unless it's *clear* from their question and their comments that they're in over their head (and judging by the comments on the answer you refer to, I trust that they know what they're talking about, and in fact it seems more like there is a different issue at hand — though I cannot comment much beyond that).

Perhaps your answer might help *someone else* with different needs from the questioner. That's fine too, and more likely than not you'll be rewarded for it with an upvote. But that doesn't necessarily mean the questioner is being stubborn or ungrateful for your help. It could also mean they just haven't found a satisfactory solution to *their* problem yet (and if this problem isn't clearly stated, the question should be edited accordingly). That's why questions on Stack Overflow are always open to new answers.

Comment: Agree. There are often several routes to solve a problem. There have been certain times when I haven't tried a suggested answer just because I knew that it would take a lot of research and development time. Or because I thought that it was a poor programming practice based on other things I had read.

Comment: Very True. I agree. Simply one question might can have different solutions or might be the questioner have different point of view.
However answer is not wasted can be helpful to others :)
Best Answer..

Comment: "Everyone has different requirements." I want to emphasize that good questions on SO should mention all requirements, if possible right from the start or as soon as they become important, otherwise how can anyone come up with a helpful alternative answer. Askers shouldn't play hide and seek with the answerers.

Comment: @Trilarion: Yeah, but mention *too* many requirements and suddenly your question runs the risk of being too specific to help anyone else (remember "too localized"?). It's vanishingly unlikely for two individuals to have the exact same set of requirements unless they're both working on the same project. You have to find a balance somewhere.

Comment: @Trilarion: All requirements?  There is a wide gulf between "It does not work" and "Here is the 47 page design document for the whole system, how do I make subcomponent Q?"

Comment: @Kevin I wanted to say: all important requirements for the actual problem. So for example the full 5 page excerpt of the 47 page design document that is necessary to understand subcomponent Q depending on how complex Q is really.

Comment: @Trilarion: If you *truly* understand the requirements well enough to know exactly which five pages to excerpt, you don't need Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Kevin Sure and if you just ask "I need Q, give me the code please" and nobody even knows what Q is then SO won't (be able to) help you either. I agree with BoltClock: a balance is needed. But I also want to say that I rather have more of the problem-specific requirements listed in the average SO question than what is the case currently. Hide and seek with the real problem in the question is inefficient. So I rather have two lines too much than one crucial line missing.

Answer (score 5):

Reading the exchange between you and OP on image getting blurred, OP seems to be *attempting* to do what you suggest. I think you did fine:  You went back-and-forth, then bowed out when OP couldn't seem to follow your instructions precisely. Let someone else come along and try.

Comment: So this question here maybe should rather be: "How to handle a questioner who has difficulties understanding the answer?".

Answer (score 5):

Relax; you answer will probably be relevant to someone else who also needs an answer. You'll get upvotes and everyone will be happy!