# Question fixed multiple times with my answer(s) but another one was accepted. Should I flag it?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

I've answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73076151/react-even-though-i-filled-the-state-it-looks-empty-in-the-render/73076203) in real-time.

The code published in question had multiple bugs, so I edited my answer multiple times.
The author updated the question's code with the fixed code after every edit I posted.

The last bug had been found by [another user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73076151/react-even-though-i-filled-the-state-it-looks-empty-in-the-render#comment129064192_73076151) and I mentioned him in my answer.

But, after the final update another user [posted an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73076382/3340702) with only the last fix, which I had already included in my answer, and the asker accepted that answer.

This doesn't seem fair to me. What I should do? Flag the answer asking for a moderator intervention? Or am I missing the point?

### Update

In the suggested post [How to deal with constant changing questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252113/how-to-deal-with-constant-changing-questions#comment7164_252129) the accepted answer point out some ways to deal with those questions. One of those ways is to "*Delete my answer and move on.*"

But a comment describes a much better approach for me.

> You should never delete your answer for such a reason. **Rollback OPs question to the most suitable revision and explain they shouldn't change it drastically.** If they won't listen and keep editing the question, flag it for moderator attention - the mods can then choose the correct path of action to take, such as locking the question in extreme cases.

From my point of view this is the best and most constructive way to deal with constant changing questions. Isn't it?

Allowing users to change their question constantly, aren't we discouraging ourself to spend time answering?

Comment: You should roll back the question when OP makes an edit that will invalidate existing answers. You already had an answer suggesting changes to their code, OP directly incorporating that in the question without any indication makes your answer feel out of place.

Comment: On MSO: [How to deal with constant changing questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252113/2821954). On MSE: [Exit strategies for "chameleon questions"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/241919)

Comment: Your update sounds like an answer, perhaps you should convert that part of your updated question to one. I guess I should also roll back your question to the most suitable revision for my answer and explain that you shouldn't change your question drastically.

Comment: Re *"Update"*: Speaking of...

Comment: not a Javascript developer, but for me the whole question looks like just "debug this code for me"

Comment: “This doesn't seem fair to me.” - Life isn’t always fair . “What I should do?” - Move on with your life and answer another question. “Flag the answer asking for a moderator intervention?” - Your flag would be rejected, a moderator has nothing to intervene, the author is the only person who can accept an answer. If another user submitted an answer, and the author of a question accepted that answer instead of your answer, there isn’t anything a moderator  can do about it. Don’t answer the question, the next time a question author, edits their questions in a similar way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Moderators won't get involved in choosing which answer is accepted and it's entirely up to the person asking the question, which (if any) answer they choose to accept.

Sometimes you just need to recognise a [chameleon question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) and move on. Ask yourself, is it worth it to put so much effort into an ever-changing question or could your time have been better spent answering four or five other solid questions?

On the other hand, if your answer is much better than any of the other answers to the question and enough people come across it, then maybe it will attract upvotes. It's still possible that you could come out on top, given time. You can have lots of upvotes, but only one accept.